# Why does the `CurrentThreadScheduler` launch immediately in outermost scope?

Tags: .net, f#, system.reactive

```ml
open System.Reactive.Concurrency
open System.Reactive.Disposables
open System

let print i = printfn "%i on thread %i" i Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule((), fun _ _ ->
    CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule((), fun _ _ -> print 3)
    print 2
    Disposable.Empty
    )

print 1
```

Output:

```
2 on thread 1
3 on thread 1
1 on thread 1
```

Why is `print 1` run last when it is in outermost scope? Why does the statement preceding it not get queued and is immediately executed unlike `CurrentThreadScheduler.Instance.Schedule((), fun _ _ -> print 3)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CurrentThreadScheduler` will:

1. Run a thunk immediately
2. If a thunk is scheduled for `t` seconds later, it will sleep for `t` seconds
3. If a thunk is already running, it will be added to a queue.

Going by these 3 rules:

1. The first scheduled item is run immediately (print 2)
2. The first item is still running while the second is scheduled, so it gets queued
3. The first item finishes, dequeues, second item is run (print 3)
4. Scheduler is done blocking, so the last line executes (print 1)

See [CurrentThreadScheduler implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/reactive/blob/master/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Concurrency/CurrentThreadScheduler.cs#L78).

`ImmediateScheduler` by contrast is just "run a thunk immediately".

Comment: But shouldn't the program in the outermost scope be in the queue already? It seems to me that something is already running when it schedules that first thunk just before `print 1`. Or am I quibbling too much here and should just take this as an implementation detail?

Comment: But the queue is free by the point it gets to print 1. It's the current thread, so it's synchronous.